behave not finding steps directory as documented?
We're using this directory structure for behave:
+-- steps/
    +-- *.step.py
+-- user1_features/
    +-- features/
        +-- *.feature

(Side note: We're using this slightly non-standard structure in anticipation of a user2_features directory that will share the steps files but have different scenarios and features.)
When invoking behave with the directory that contains the features directory, it works as documented:
$ behave user1_features
Feature: Begin the beguine # user1_features/features/begin.feature:1
... etc ...

But when naming a specific feature file, behave fails to find the steps:
$ behave user1_features/features/beguine.feature
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 
'C:/Users/.../user1_features/features/steps'

The problem
The documentation states that on the command line you can specify:

the path to a “name.feature” file
This tells behave where to find
the feature file. To find the steps directory behave will look in the
directory containing the feature file. If it is not present, behave
will look in the parent directory, and then its parent, and so on
until it hits the root of the filesystem.

While the first invocation found the steps directory, the second one -- which named a specific features file -- did not.
Is this:

a bug in the implementation?
a bug in the documentation?
a bug in my reading of the docs?

